# Google maps directions - spaces between polylines

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, directions

I am facing this ugly problem, can anyone solve this ? I want to get rid of that ugly spacec between lines. I need to keep the width.[image]

code(adding polylines) :

```
thread {
        val response = getResponse(points[1].location, points[2].location, "driving21.").log()
        when (response) {

            is Result.Failure -> "Fail".log()

            is Result.Success ->
                response.value.routes[0].listOfLegs[0].listOfSteps.forEach { element ->
                    //                    element.points.log()
                    val options = PolylineOptions()
                    options.color(Color.rgb(255, 26, 140))
                    options.width(50F)
                    options.addAll(PolyUtil.decode(element.points))
                    runOnUiThread {
                        map.addPolyline(options)
                    }
                }
        }
```

EDIT:[image]

after adding `.jointType(JointType.ROUND)`
there is another problem

Comment: thank you, i should have read documentations more carefully :) thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.jointType(JointType.ROUND)` Adding this line should do it for you

Comment: there is another problem, as i posted. Is it even possible to fix ?

Comment: This might be because of the lat-long obtained. It is based on the points so I think the points obtained might be such so it has to go out of place.

Comment: but how to fix that ? i cannot edit JSON which i recieved

Comment: You are using which API?

Comment: This is great news!!